# Git for windows bash execution path for a script not correct

Tags: git, bash, git-bash, git-for-windows

When the code

```
SRC=$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd)
```

is executed inside a Bash script on a system that has Git for Windows installed in `c:\program files\Git`, the SRC will get the value `/c/program`.

How do I make this work?
I need to get the path to where the script is and use that to include other scripts with a relative path.
In my case the next line is: 
source "${SRC}/common/common.sh"

The script is in `c:\program files\Git\usr\bin` so I can use `git <command-name>` and extend Git with some useful hand-made commands for feature branch workflow with rebase and submodules.
The source code is at https://github.com/jlovs/git-scripts if anyone want to help out.

Comment: Please share more information about the environment: Are you running under Cygwin?

Comment: I'm running MINGW64

Comment: @JanLovstrand – there may be some ambiguity in exactly what you are asking. After reading it a second time, I honestly have no clue. What do you want `SRC` to be exactly?

Comment: Wait, I think I get it. You need to resolve the src directory: how about `SRC=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )`

Comment: @JanLovstrand – if this is incorrect please clarify the question.

Comment: @TravisClarke I need the directory where the script is, so I can include other scripts with a relative path. Updating the question with that information now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double-quote the argument of the `cd` command.

```
SRC=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)
```

The command substitution `$(dirname "$0")` expands to a path containing a space. The following `cd` command gets two arguments while you want to pass just one, with a space inside.

You don’t need to worry about the quotes around `$0` inside another pair of quotes since the `$()` command substitution starts a new [quoting context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118438/54675).

Comment: This answer is perfectly valid, but for the double quote lovers out there (which I assume all Windows users **need** to be): `SRC="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; "pwd")"`

Comment: This one works. Sorry if I didn't notice that it was an included script that had the same error. Thank you all!

Comment: Shouldn't you escape internal quotes? `SRC=$(cd "$(dirname \"$0\")"; pwd)`

Comment: @phd No, see the last paragraph of my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, you are running under MINGW64. You can try to use `cygpath -aw` to convert the path to windows format:

```
SRC=$(cygpath -aw $(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd))
```

More information [here](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) and [here](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html).

Comment: Think the problem is in the $(dirname "$0") part of the line, because this gives me a "too many arguments" error. I think that the space in the path has to be escaped like /c/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin, but don't know how to make that happen. Tried cygpath -u, but it gives me /c/Program Files/usr/bin

Comment: Try cygpath -aw

Comment: Please verify spaces, quotes, etc